# Numerical integration of a double integral using Gauss-Legendre quadrature

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I already have a code for generating the weights and abscissas for the Gaussian-Legendre quadrature rule for integration but I am having difficulty in using it for double integrals.

To generate the weights and abscissas I use the following notation [w,x]=leg(x1,x2,n) where w are the weights, x are the abscissas, x1 is the lower limit of the integral, x2 is the upper limit, and n is the number of quadrature points.

I'll just give a simple example so that it can help me understand the idea. Suppose I have the following integral $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^2 y^2 dx dy$ 
How do I implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Double integrals are integrals over a rectangular domain. They can either be treated with dedicated rectangular schemes or – what you attempt to do – with *product schemes* from one-dimensional quadrature. You could even mix and match two different schemes here.

The points of the product schemes are the 1D points in a Cartesian product, i.e., for every `x_i` from scheme 1 and `y_j` from scheme 2, `(x_i, y_j)` is a point in the product scheme. The weights are the product of the two corresponding weights.

[image]

If you want to make it easy on you, you could use [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (a project of mine):

```
import numpy
import quadpy

quadpy.quadrilateral.integrate(
    lambda x: numpy.exp(x[0]),
    [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]],
    quadpy.quadrilateral.Product(quadpy.line_segment.GaussLegendre(4))
    )
```